# Combine timedelta and date column, group by time interval

Tags: datetime, pandas, timedelta

I need to combine two separate columns to one datetime column.

The pandas dataframe looks as follows:

```
calendarid    time_delta_actualdeparture    actualtriptime
20140101      0 days 06:35:49.000020000     27.11666667
20140101      0 days 06:51:37.000020000     24.83333333
20140101      0 days 07:11:40.000020000     28.1
20140101      0 days 07:31:40.000020000     23.03333333
20140101      0 days 07:53:34.999980000     23.3
20140101      0 days 08:14:13.000020000     51.81666667
```

I would like to convert it to look like this:

```
calendarid               actualtriptime
2014-01-01 6:30:00       mean of trip times in time interval
2014-01-01 7:00:00       mean of trip times in time interval 
2014-01-01 7:30:00       mean of trip times in time interval
2014-01-01 8:00:00       mean of trip times in time interval
2014-01-01 8:30:00       mean of trip times in time interval
```

Essentially i would like to combine the two columns as one and then group into 30 minute time intervals, taking the mean of the actual trip time in that interval. I've unsuccessfully tried many techniques, but i am still learning python/pandas. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your 'calendarid' column to a datetime and add the delta to get the starting times.

```
In [5]: df['calendarid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calendarid'], format='%Y%m%d')


In [7]: df['calendarid'] = df['calendarid'] + df['time_delta_actualdeparture']

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                  calendarid  time_delta_actualdeparture  actualtriptime
0 2014-01-01 06:35:49.000020             06:35:49.000020       27.116667
1 2014-01-01 06:51:37.000020             06:51:37.000020       24.833333
2 2014-01-01 07:11:40.000020             07:11:40.000020       28.100000
3 2014-01-01 07:31:40.000020             07:31:40.000020       23.033333
4 2014-01-01 07:53:34.999980             07:53:34.999980       23.300000
5 2014-01-01 08:14:13.000020             08:14:13.000020       51.816667
```

Then you can you set your date column as an index and resample at the 30 minutes frequency to get the mean over each interval.

```
In [19]: df.set_index('calendarid').resample('30Min', how='mean', label='right')
Out[19]: 
                     actualtriptime
calendarid                         
2014-01-01 07:00:00       25.975000
2014-01-01 07:30:00       28.100000
2014-01-01 08:00:00       23.166667
2014-01-01 08:30:00       51.816667
```